My producer-consumer implementation is exceeding maximum size
I have implemented a Runnable Producer and a Runnable Consumer alongwith a Store class. The Store has a shelf of maximum size allocated. Each producer adds an item and each consumer will remove an item. I am using a CachedThreadPool to create both types of the threads where each thread run on a infinite loop. I have also implemented two separate semaphore for Runnable class with the Producer getting the initial Permit size equal to the max Shelf size of the Store and the consumer's initial permit set to zero.
When I run the code I received a runtime error of IndexOutOfBoundsException, I understood the problem for this is the 'this.items.size()-1' line where two consumer read the same index and try to remove them leading to the above error. But I also received another unexpected result where the count of my List holding the items is exceeding the shelf size. For example in the below code, I set the initial maxShelfs size as 5 and gave Producer the permit size of 5. But I kept getting the output as "Consumer size: 6" following this I tried to put a breakpoint in the addItem method when list size exceeds the maxShelf size. Several runs confirmed that the list size did reach 6 and that this happens rarely. I am unable to understand why the list size is 6 when the actual permit is limited?
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Semaphore ps = new Semaphore(5);
        Semaphore cs = new Semaphore(0);
        Store s = new Store(5,ps,cs);
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for(int i =0;i<8;i++)
        {
            es.execute(new Producer(s,ps,cs));
        }
        for(int i =0;i<20;i++)
        {
            es.execute(new Consumer(s,ps,cs));
        }
    }
}


public class Store {
    private List<Object> items;
    public int maxShelfs;
    Semaphore ps;
    Semaphore cs;

    public Store (int maxShelfs,Semaphore ps, Semaphore cs)
    {
        this.ps = ps;
        this.cs = cs;
        this.maxShelfs = maxShelfs;
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getMaxShelfs()
    {
        return maxShelfs;
    }

    public List<Object> getItems()
    {
        return items;
    }

    public void addItem()
    {

        System.out.println("Producer size: "+this.items.size());
        this.items.add(new Object());
        if(items.size()==6) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }

    public void removeItem()
    {

        System.out.println("Consumer size: "+this.items.size());
        this.items.remove(this.items.size()-1);
    }
}


public class Consumer implements Runnable{
    private Store s;
    Semaphore ps;
    Semaphore cs;

    public Consumer(Store s, Semaphore ps, Semaphore cs)
    {
        this.ps = ps;
        this.cs = cs;
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                cs.acquire();
//                Thread.sleep(20);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            if (s.getItems().size() > 0)
            {
                s.removeItem();
            }
            ps.release();
        }
    }
}


public class Producer implements Runnable{
    private Store s;
    Semaphore ps;
    Semaphore cs;

    public Producer (Store s,Semaphore ps,Semaphore cs)
    {
        this.ps = ps;
        this.cs = cs;
        this.s = s;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                ps.acquire();
//                Thread.sleep(20);
                if (s.getItems().size() < s.getMaxShelfs()) {
                    s.addItem();
                }
                cs.release();

            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }



        }
    }
}

I am trying to learn concurrency and have not learnt more about try and catch so my inital point was to look at a rare case where overlapping of list size reads in the condition due to misreads during the run method might lead this but I was not able to come up with such test case (I was told that List is not thread-safe and I should use a concurrent data structure).
The case where list size is 6

You accessing Store in non thread safe manner.

Your Store class has fields, ps and cs, that are not used anywhere.

Your Store class allows a caller to access it's private items field. Even if your demo program used Store in a thread-safe way (It doesn't) giving callers access to private members of a class automatically disqualifies the class from being called "thread safe." Thread safety should be a guarantee that your code won't get into a bad state if it's called from more than one thread, but there is no way you can give that guarantee if you give callers access to your private state variables.

Your store is not thread-safe. Since both the producer and consumer are modifying the store, they cannot operate in parallel. You need to serialize the add and remove operations using a mutex. If you want to use a semaphore, you only need one instance that only one thread passes through:
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

You need to use this semaphore when adding elements:
semaphore.acquire();
try {
    if (s.getItems().size() < s.getMaxShelfs()) {
        s.addItem();
    }
} finally {
    semaphore.release();
}

The same semaphore must be used when removing elements:
semaphore.acquire();
try {
    if (s.getItems().size() > 0) {
        s.removeItem();
    }
} finally {
    semaphore.release();
}


Just a point of style: If you want to use a Semaphore as a mutex lock for some reason instead of using ReentrantLock, that's OK. It works. But, why not at least name the variable lock or something like instead of naming it semaphore. Semaphores can be used in a variety of different ways. If you name the variable lock, it makes you code just a bit easier to read because everybody can more quickly see what it's for.

@SolomonSlow The semaphore variable is called that way because it has the Semaphore type. If the variable had the ReentrantLock type, it would be logical to call it lock. But it has the Semaphore type.

Do you name all of your int variables integer, or maybe int1, int2, etc.? If not, why not? Probably you don't because ints can represent many different things, and when you see a variable being used in the code, need to know what it represents. If your code declares some bespoke type, Fubar, and you keep one in a variable named fubar, that's fine. That might be for the best because there's probably only one thing that "fubar" can mean. But, There are dozens of things that "semaphore" could mean.

P.S., Most programmers these days are using IDEs, and in most IDEs, if you want to know the type of a variable, its trivially easy to find out.

@SolomonSlow The name of the variable should reflect its purpose. If the purpose of the variable is to hold a reference to a semaphore, then it is logical to name the variable semaphore. If you name the variable lock, then you hide the fact that in this particular case, an inappropriate Semaphore was used to implement the synchronization logic instead of a suitable ReentrantLock.

Yes, and if the purpose of a variable is to hold an int value, then it is logical to name the variable "integer" (or something like.) If you name the variable accountBalance then you hide the fact that in [a certain] particular case, an inappropriate int was used to hold an amount of currency instead of a suitable long. [P.S., You are they one who used a Semaphore for mutual exclusion. If you think that's "inappropriate," then why did you do it? Why didn't you use ReentrantLock in your example?]

@SolomonSlow To minimize the number of changes in ReD's code. If he uses Semaphore, there must have been a reason for it. Maybe he is currently learning how Semaphore works.

Thanks for the answer, Andrey. I actually have studied about locks, synchronized as well as semaphore. My instructor was teaching how we can allow multiple threads to access the critical section using semaphore and finally he showed that the List we are using is not thread-safe and suggested to use thread-safe data structure like ConcurrentLinkedQueue or ConcurrentHashMap. I understood that but my question here is simple, When the permit for ProducerSemaphore is limited to 5, how can producer reach to a point to add 6 items without an extra permit, this should not happen even after mis-reads.

Your code lacks mutual exclusion. In a nutshell, you have a stateful object, the Store, you have multiple threads that want to see the state, and at least one of those threads wants to change the state.
Changing the state (e.g., addItem(), removeItem()) has more than a single step, and if one thread looks at the state at the moment when some other thread is half-way done changing it, the thread that's looking can see something inconsistent. Anything could happen as a result; The program could throw an exception, Items could disappear from the list,  Duplicates could appear, the JVM could crash with a segfault. The behavior of your program is undefined.
Mutual exclusion looks like this:
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Store {
    private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    ...
    public void addItem() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            ...access/modify shared state variables...
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    ...
}

The lock.lock() call causes the calling thread to "own" the lock, and only one thread will ever be allowed to own the same lock at the same time. If thread A calls lock.lock() while thread B "owns" it, the lock.lock() call in thread A simply will not return until thread B relinquishes ownership by calling lock.unlock().
Locking and unlocking also does something that goes by several names; "synchronization," "memory visibility," and "happens before relationship." On a system with more than one CPU (which is most workstations/laptops/servers/mobile devices these days) using locks will ensure that changes caused by code running on one CPU will be communicated to code running on other CPUs.  In a nutshell: Every change that thread B made before it called lock.unlock() is guaranteed to be visible to thread A after thread A subsequently completes a lock.lock() call.
There are some more advanced approaches to solving synchronization problems and mutating shared state, but as a beginner, your focus should be on using mutex locks.
As a complete beginner, you should start with having just one lock. There are some very good reasons for having more than one lock, but until you get the hang of it...

Lock the lock before writing or reading any shared variable,
Don't unlock the lock until all of the shared variables are in a state that other threads should be allowed to see.

Extra credit:

Don't sleep() or do anything else that takes a long time while keeping the lock locked. If you think you need to wait for something while locked, maybe there's a way you can (a) back off, release the lock without changing anything, (b) wait, and then (c) try again.


Thanks for the answer Solomon. I have pretty much studied about synchronization problems and how to overcome them using locks, synchronized, Concurrent Data Stuctures and Semaphore. My instructor was using this code to tell us how we can allow multiple threads to access the critical section. Using a simple lock would defeat the purpose as either a producer or a consumer can run at a time. My question is actually different, I want to know why does the List size exceed 5, when my producer only get 5 max permits, I have understood and informed by my instructor that the List is not a -(1/2)

thread-safe data structure and we should opt for thread-safe data structure. But I have focusing on my question from days but still cannot understand why the List size is exceeding 5. I did not come up with such a scenario multiple producer-consumer OR producer-producer read critical section together and then context switch , the number will never change as they will never release a permit before making changes to the store.

@ReD, Your use of ps and cs semaphores ensures that the total number of addItem calls minus the total number of removeItem calls will never be greater than 5, but you do nothing to prevent the not-thread-safe ArrayList object from being corrupted by concurrent modifications in several threads. If you allow not-thread-safe data to be concurrently modified by more than one thread, then there's no point in trying to answer questions like, "why does the list size exceed 5?"

@ReD, ...Fix that problem first, and then if you still find more than five items in the list, then we'll have something to talk about.
